# User defined SQL type equivalent in Enterprise library

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, enterprise-library, user-defined-types

I'm trying to pass parameter which is a table type in SQL Server. I'm unable to find compatible c# type.

I'm passing multiple parameters to stored procedure and one of the parameter is user defined type in SQL.

```
Database Connection = new SqlDatabase(ConnectionString);
DbCommand Cmd= Connection.GetStoredProcCommand("ProcedureName");
..................
Connection.AddInParameter(Cmd, "@custom", DbType.Object, custom);
```

Stored procedure looks like this:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureName]
  @custom dbo.CstmType READONLY 
AS
```

This code is throwing following error :

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 6 ("@custom"): Data type 0x62 (sql_variant) has an invalid type for type-specific metadata

I'm tired on finding an answer to this question on internet. Can somebody please provide fruitful suggestion how to get ride of this error and what should be the appropriate datatype?

Comment: What is the SQL definition of dbo.CstmType and what C# value are you trying to pass for @custom?

Comment: By "user defined type" do you mean a table type (`CREATE TYPE dbo.CstmType AS TABLE ...`), an alias type (`CREATE TYPE dbo.CstmType FROM numeric(30,2)`), a C# user-defined data type, or something else? Please be specific and provide the definition.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : Yes. By user defined type means CREATE TYPE dbo.CstmType AS TABLE ...

Comment: The Enterrpise Library Data block was abandoned over 10 years ago because its functionality became part of ADO.NET itself. That's why you can't find any documentation or answers any more. As Shivani shows, it's actually easier to use ADO.NET

Comment: In any case, Entlib works on top of ADO.NET, it doesn't replace it. The only way to use a table-valued parameter in ADO.NET is to use a DataTable. This means that `DbType.Object` is wrong

Comment: Wait, what Enterprise Library are you talking about? *Microsoft's* Enterprise Library was [last updated 6 years ago](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff648951(v=pandp.10)) and its site [clearly warns it's no longer updated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff648951(v=pandp.10))

Answer (score 3):

In your C# code, create DataTable with same fields you have added in your user define table type.
Such as,

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("column1");
dt.Columns.Add("column2");
```

After that, insert data in this table,like,

```
dt.Rows.Add(new Object[]{ value1,value2 });
```

Add parameter in procedure call like below,

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName", con)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
var List = new SqlParameter("@custom", SqlDbType.Structured);
List.TypeName = "CstmType";
List.Value = dt;
cmd.Parameters.Add(List);
```

In your stored procedure, add parameters for user defined table type

```
@custom dbo.CstmType READONLY
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm trying to do the same thing but with Enterprise library.

Comment: @ManishDhariwal why? The data block was abandoned over 10 years ago because its functionality became part of ADO.NET itself. Which version of Entlib are you using?

Comment: @ManishDhariwal in any case, EntLib works on top of ADO.NET, it doesn't replace it. To pass a table-valued parameter you have to use a DataTable. This means that  `DbType.Object` is the wrong type.